# The SDK platform-tools version ((23)) is too old to check APIs compiled with API 23

Tags: android, android-studio

I am getting this strange error on the first line of each file in my Android Studio. Everything was OK until I updated my Android Studio. Could someone explain to me what's going on and how to get rid of such error? I'd appreciate any help with it.

P.S: Despite this error, I can compile and run my code successfully.

Comment: @Alok that one is different. "The SDK platform-tools version ((22)) is too old to check APIs compiled with API 23" sounds more logical than "The SDK platform-tools version ((23)) is too old to check APIs compiled with API 23".

Comment: if the error was " The SDK Platform-tools version ((20)) is too old to check APIs compiled with API 22" then, what should i do if i choose not to update my SDK? @Freezy

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Update your android sdk platform-tools to the revision 23.0.1 from sdk manager.
In android studio click File->Invalidate Caches/Restart...

That's it. The error must be gone now.

Comment: @MichaelKessler how did you end up solving it?

Comment: @stack, I didn't have time and changed the entire project SDK to 21... Will try to figure out later..

Comment: Updating my platform-tools worked for me (I didn't need to invalidate caches). To update, go to Android Studio -> Check for updates (Mac). Note that updating Android Studio itself did *not* fix it. It was specifically updating platform-tools.

Answer (score 4):

Like the error says, the Platform-tools needs to be on a newer version. 
To update,

1. Open `SDK manager`
2. At the bottom of the dialog box, click on link `Launch Standalone SDK Manager` -> Rev will be 23.01
3. Install the updated package
4. Invalidate cache as `File -> Invalidate caches/Restart"`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem on windows as follows:

Go to Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager -> click on 
Update the android Android SDK platform tools to  the latest one.
Once it is done updating, the error should be gone.

That is what worked for me hope it works for you too..
Cheers

Comment: How's this differ from the other answers?

Answer (score 0):

first you should update your SDK, for update go to SDK Manager and click on install packages. if this button is not active, click on Tools->Options->Clear cache and then close SDK Manager and reopen it. now your button is active. after update SDK Manager go to android studio and click on File->Invalidate cache/Restart->Invalidate cache/Restart.
now your problem is solved. enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, the way I solve it was that press Alt+Enter and choose Disable Inspection, it will remove the error, I hope this will work for you too.[image]