# The SDK platform-tools version (23.1) is too old to check APIs compiled with API 25 - android

Tags: android, android-studio

This is my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.wokoshop.sony.app"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 32
        versionName "4.16"
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }

}
```

I am seeing following error in my all java files.

```
The SDK platform-tools version (23.1) is too old to check APIs compiled with API 25.
```

I am not using/seeing anywhere 23.1?

Why this error? how to fix this?

Comment: did you check all build.gradle file?

Comment: Have you updated Android Studio to the latest platform tools? Go to File > Settings, then navigate to Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK and click on the SDK Tools tab.

Comment: ^ I was thinking same.

Comment: Try update studio. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33184819/the-sdk-platform-tools-version-23-is-too-old-to-check-apis-compiled-with-api)